# How do I check the type of error in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Let's say I have an error:

```
.catch((err) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'url-error.html'));
  console.log(err.message);
});
```

How can I check the error type?

e.g.

```
if (err.message.toLowerCase().contains('invalid operator')) {
  console.log('this is me doing something in this block');
} else {
  console.log('nothing is happening here');
}
```

P.S. I am catching the error from a library on Node.JS called "ytdl-core".

Comment: Have you checked `err.name`?

Comment: `console.log(err)`. What do you get? Maybe there is something in there that you can use to identify the error

Comment: err object itself gives you the error that has been generated, what else you need man ?

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya I need to get the error as a string so that I can perform methods like toLowerCase() and contains() on the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check error code

```
if (err.code =='ERR_AMBIGUOUS_ARGUMENT') {
  console.log('this is me doing something in this block');
} else {
  console.log('nothing is happening here');
}
```

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/errors.html#errors_node_js_error_codes

you can use [`instanceof`](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_class_rangeerror) for type

```
catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof RangeError) {
      // Output expected RangeError.
      console.log(e);
    } else {
      // Output unexpected Errors.
      console.log(e, false);
    }
  }
```

Comment: The thing is that I can't do a method on the string like err.code.contains(); or toLowerCase.

Comment: code is String type so you can do like err.code.contains(); or toLowerCase.

Comment: @raphtlw What version of node are you using?

Comment: @some i'm using node.js 13.